# how to get notification after inserting elements into dom in ember js

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, components

My issue is as below: 

*****************************************Scenario***********************************

I have an ember component which has a boolean variable. When this boolean variable is true then a condition in its correspoding template gets fulfilled and its contents are inserted into DOM.

```
exports default Ember.component.extend({
checkVariable:false,
setCheckVariable:function()
{
this.set('checkVariable',true);
}
});

<div id="wrapper">
{{#if checkVariable:false}}
<div id="itemToBeInserted">
<span>
</span>
</div
{{/if}}
</div>
```

As per ember, whenever checkVariable is true #itemToBeInserted is inserted into dom and when checkVariable is false, #itemToBeInserted is removed from dom. 

i want to add keypress event handler to #itemToBeInserted and also do $('#itemToBeInserted').trigger('focus') when checkVariable is true i.e.set when #itemToBeInserted is inserted into DOM.

*****************************************Problem***********************************

In order to do $('#itemToBeInserted').on('keypress',function(){}) and $('#itemToBeInserted').trigger('focus'); the #itemToBeInserted has to be in the dom. Lets say we can do $("#wrapper").on('keypress','#itemToBeInserted',func...); but to do $('#itemToBeInserted').trigger('focus'); #itemToBeInserted has to be in dom.
Now inside setCheckVariable assume i want to do the below:

```
setCheckVariable:function()
    {
    this.set('checkVariable',true);
$('#itemToBeInserted').on('keypress',function(){}); 
$('#itemToBeInserted').trigger('focus');
    }
```

Now even though i set checkVariable to true it takes time to insert #itemToBeInserted to dom but the next two statements get executed i.e. $('#itemToBeInserted').on('keypress',function(){}); 
    $('#itemToBeInserted').trigger('focus'); These two wont work since #itemToBeInserted is not in dom!!!!! I want to know how to know when a particular part is inserted to dom after inserting something like didInsertElement but for an if condition!!!! Basically i want to know how to carry on few instructions after an element is inserted into dom,as in can we schedule it or have a callback called?

*****************************************Methods tried***********************************
1>This method worked but i dont want to use setTimeout.

```
setCheckVariable:function()
        {
        this.set('checkVariable',true);
         var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function(){_this.itemLoaded();},100);

        }
itemLoaded:function()
{
if(!document.getElementById('itemToBeInserted'))
        {
var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function(){_this.itemLoaded();},100);
return false;
        }
  $('#itemToBeInserted').on('keypress',function(){}); 
    $('#itemToBeInserted').trigger('focus');

}
```

2>i have used binding in the following different ways but the problem here is the first time the application gets loaded the binded computer properties get called however after the application is loaded the binded computed properties dont get called, it acts as thothe variable is cached

```
<div id="wrapper">
    {{#if checkVariable:false}}
    <div id="itemToBeInserted">
{{if loaded}}
{{/if}}
    <span>
    </span>
    </div
    {{/if}}
    </div>
setCheckVariable:function()//this function is called after clicking a button, so first time application is loaded and we click the button loaded computer property gets called after that it does not get called
            {
            this.set('checkVariable',true);                  
            }
loaded:function()
{
console.log('this gets hit only once when application is loaded and not after that');
}.property()
```

or

```
<div id="wrapper">
    {{#if checkVariable:false}}
    <div id="itemToBeInserted" {{bind-attr class = "loaded:loaded"}}>
    <span>
    </span>
    </div
    {{/if}}
    </div>
setCheckVariable:function()//this function is called after clicking a button, so first time application is loaded and we click the button loaded computer property gets called after that it does not get called
            {
            this.set('checkVariable',true);                  
            }
loaded:function()
{
console.log('this gets hit only once when application is loaded and not after that');
}.property()
```

OR

```
<div id="wrapper">
    {{#if checkVariable:false}}
    <div id="itemToBeInserted">
<img src="" id="checkLoad" style="display:none;"/>
    <span>
    </span>
    </div
    {{/if}}
    </div>
setCheckVariable:function()//this function is called after clicking a button, so first time application is loaded and we click the button loaded computer property gets called after that it does not get called
            {
this.$().on('load',checkLoad,this.loaded); //unfortunately loaded is one of those events that does not load
            this.set('checkVariable',true);                  
            }
loaded:function()
{
console.log('this gets hit only once when application is loaded and not after that');
}.property()
```

3>

```
<div id="wrapper">
    {{#if checkVariable:false}}
    <div id="itemToBeInserted">
{{if loaded}}
{{/if}}
    <span>
    </span>
    </div
    {{/if}}
    </div>
setCheckVariable:function()//this function is called after clicking a button, so first time application is loaded and we click the button loaded computer property gets called after that it does not get called
            {
            this.set('checkVariable',true);                  
            }
loaded:function()
{
console.log('this gets hit only once when application is loaded and not after that');
}.property('checkVariable') //now loaded gets called but not when #itemToBeInserted is insertedIntoDom but when checkVariable changes again useless
```

> I have also tried to create another component for #itemToBeInserted
>   but apparantly we cant append  one component into another since they
>   are subviews.  I also tried using Ember.handlerbars.compile()  but
>   luck there, some problem again.

It looks to me as if the changes are to be reflected only one way that is from component.js to template.hbs and not the other way round in ember.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

After much head breaking came up with this solution.

```
    setCheckVariable:function()
                {
var _this = this;    
    Ember.run(function()            //called in the format saard
                {
                    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender',function(){    //this gets executed later          
                        if(_this.get('checkVariable'))
                        {                       
                            var $item= $(document.getElementById('itemTobeInserted'));

                            $item.on('keydown', function(evt){_this.handleKeyPress(evt);});

                            $item.trigger('focus');
                        }                                           
                    });
                    Ember.run.schedule('sync',function(){       //this gets executed first
                        _this.set('checkVariable',true);   
                    });

                });            
                }
```

Even though my problem is solved, however i would still like to know how to make a computer.property called always and not just once when the application loads